# Corlib not in sync error on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I have application built in mono on ubuntu 15. 
When i try to run application on test machine, i get an error

```
"Corlib not in sync with this runtime: expected corlib version 111, found 117.
Loaded from: mscorlib.dll
Download a newer corlib or a newer runtime at http://www.go-mono.com/daily."
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the Mono runtime you're using is a different version than the Mono class libraries, specifically the corlib.

How did you install Mono? I'd suggest using the official packages: http://www.mono-project.com